# Не срабатывают методы onListItemClick и onItemLongClick

Tags: java, android

При создании класса указал интерфейс `OnItemClickListener`. Сами же элементы списка представляют собой layout, прописанный в xml-разметке. Когда использовал вместо них встроенный `simple_list_item_1`, то все работало.

`Notes` здесь - это отдельный класс, наследник `HashMap`. В его объектах хранятся данные для одного элемента

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    private DatabaseManager mDatabaseManager;
    private SQLiteDatabase dbHelp;



    public void add() {
        Intent newNote = new Intent(this,addNote.class);
        startActivity(newNote);
    }

    private void outputNotes() {
        mDatabaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        dbHelp = mDatabaseManager.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = dbHelp.query(mDatabaseManager.DB_TABLE,new String[]{mDatabaseManager.NOTES_HEADER_COLUMN,
                mDatabaseManager.NOTES_NOTE_COLUMN},null,null,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String headerNote, bodyNote;
        ArrayList<Notes> NotesList = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        while(cursor.isAfterLast()==false)
        {
            headerNote = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDatabaseManager.NOTES_HEADER_COLUMN));
            bodyNote = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDatabaseManager.NOTES_NOTE_COLUMN));
            NotesList.add(new Notes(headerNote,bodyNote));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,NotesList,R.layout.view_notes,
                new String[]{Notes.HEADER, Notes.BODY}, new int[]{R.id.header_of_note,R.id.body_of_note});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        outputNotes();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        outputNotes();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Работает",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Длинное нажатие",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде, методы не те... Должно быть нечто типа `protected void onItemClickListener` и `...onItemLongClickListener`, кажется. Еще я не вижу кому именно вы эти методы сетите. 
Вероятно ошибаюсь, не работал с этим

Comment: А теперь работает только долгое нажатие?